# How to debug File Drop Area Information during Uploading File?

Tags: content-editor, fieldtype

I added a File Drop Area field (let's call it FDA) into a content item (let's call it `sitecore/content/Home`).

In Dialog "Upload File", after I uploaded a file and **click "Upload"**, where can I find the information on my item `(sitecore/content/Home`) and my FDA field?

I wanted to do some specific action when the dialog is opened from File Drop Area, but this action should not be done on other "Upload File" functionality such as the one comes from Media Library.

I need to know if this dialog is opened from File Drop Area or the "Upload File" from Media library for example. I have debugged `UploadArgs` from my custom processor in `<uiUpload>` pipeline and `Sitecore.Context` object, but I haven't found them (or I might have overlooked it).

Which place should I look into to debug the information on FDA and `sitecore/content/Home`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**uiUpload** pipeline is used when you upload files into Media Library .

In your case you have to look how Content Editor Fields are created :

https://www.sitecore.net/company/blog/474/creating-a-custom-sitecore-field-4246

You need to override  FileDropArea field.

You need to use reflector or other decompile tool to get code  for class : **Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.FileDropArea** and to create your own class .

I recommend you to duplicate the item : **/sitecore/system/Field types/System Types/File Drop Area**

You have to modify Control field to  customcontent:FileDropArea .

[image]

You need to declare your customcontent  on controlsources section of config file

```
<controlSources>
 <source mode="on" namespace="yourNamespace" assembly="yourassembly" prefix="customcontent"  />
</controlSources>
```